# 3 div (left, center, right), div goes down if size < min-width

Tags: html, css, fill

So I have 3 Divs. Left, center right.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuXwD.png)

If browser size smaller than center min-width, it goes down. Video:

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llQERr49LkE)

I don't know what do I wrong, so many people tried to help me + I searched for it but I didn't find anything. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent
{
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
overflow: auto;
}

#left {
position: relative;
width: 370px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
background: #093F5C;
overflow: hidden;
}
#right {
position: relative;
width: 230px;
height: 100%;
float: right;
background: #093F5C;
overflow: auto;
}
#center {
height: 100%;
min-width: 550px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes http://jsfiddle.net/35bxtc2z/6/ (center min-width is 100)

Comment: What is your desired behavior? Do you want the parent div to overflow the viewport?

Comment: #center disappears if it have less width than min-width (100px;) I would like to make it scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe...

```
#left {
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 370px;
   height: 100%;
   background: #093F5C;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #093F5C;
  overflow: auto;
 }

 #center { 
   height: 100%;
   position:absolute;
   left: 370px; /*width of leftDiv */
   right: 230px; /*width of rightDiv */
   top:0px;
   /*min-width: 100px;*/
   overflow: auto;
   background: red;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/35bxtc2z/7/ (i have change the dimension fixed of the left and right div). Is this what you search?

Answer (score 0):

The `#center` should have a max-width:550px, not a min-width:550px. You'll also probably want to add a width to it as well.

```
#center {
    height:100%;
    max-width:550px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

There's also a lot of other odd things about your CSS in general, but thats beyond the scope of this question... Some things to think about - why does the `#parent` have a `position:fixed` ? Why is everything else `position:relative` ? And why do you have heights of 100% ?

Comment: Because there's header and footer, this is why parent fixed position.

Comment: And I use relative to divs because there's position: absolute; divs inside them so If I don't use relative the child divs would be weird